# Why "Action Mailer" is not rendering the email template?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, templates, actionmailer

I am using "Action Mailer" in Ruby on Rails application to send emails. I have the following action mailer:

```
class SecurityUserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default from: 'myemail@gmail.com'

  def password_reset(security_user)
    @security_user = security_user
    mail to: security_user.email, subject: 'Password Reset'
  end

  def email_confirmation(security_user)
    @security_user = security_user
    mail to: security_user.email, subject: 'Account Created'
  end

end
```

I am successfully sending emails but the second method (email_confirmation) is not using the corresponding template.

The email templates are in views/security_users_mailer folder and named as follows:

1. email_confirmation.txt.erb
2. password_reset.txt.erb

Why only the password_reset template is used?

Note, firstly, I thought that maybe there is something wrong with the code in my template but then I replace it with text content and it is not rendered again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was caused by file extension TYPO. I have

> email_confirmation.**txt**.erb

and a mailer template should be with extension **text** or **html**.

As you see from the [official docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-views) - the template with the same mailer action is used by default if exists.

Answer (score 4):

**Rails 4** I had this same issue, but mine was caused by having an empty layout in `layouts/mailer.html.erb`

Comment: Of course. Seeing your answer made my issue so obvious in hindsight.

Answer (score 2):

I believe an alternative would be to specify the template you would like to render the following is an example how you may go about this

```
class SecurityUserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'myemail@gmail.com'
  def password_reset(security_user)
    @security_user = security_user
    mail to: security_user.email, subject: 'Password Reset'
  end

  def email_confirmation(security_user)
    @security_user = security_user
    mail (:to =>  security_user.email, 
          :subject => 'Account Created', 
          :template_path => 'email_confirmation.txt.erb',
          :template_name => 'another')
  end
end
```

Take a look at the following should provide some further insight:

[Mailer Views](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-views)

or look at

[Api Ruby on Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) You will see example where it says `Or even render a special view` so that alternatively you could have inside your `mail` block the following:

```
mail (:to =>  security_user.email, 
              :subject => 'Account Created') do |format|
               format.html { render 'another_template' }
               format.text { render :text => 'email_confirmation.txt.erb' }
      end
```

This should shed some light on what you are trying to accomplish